# read external data in a spark-streaming job

Tags: amazon-s3, hdfs, spark-streaming

Suppose a system is generating a batch of data every 1h on `hdfs` or `aws-s3`, like this

```
s3://..../20170901-00/     # generated at 0am
s3://..../20170901-01/     # 1am
...
```

and I need to pipe these batches of data into `kafka` once they're generated.

My solution for this is, set up a `spark-streaming` job and set a moderate job interval (say, half an hour), so at each `streaming` interval try to read from `s3` and if the data is there, then read it and write to `kafka`.

Is this doable? And I don't know how to read from `s3` or `hdfs` in a `spark-streaming` job, how?